# Snapkit seems to be blocking all the GestureRecognizers on subviews

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've created a custom UIView which has a UITapGestureRecognizer added to it in it's own init:

```
class BoxView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.construct()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.construct()
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    func construct() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.frame.size = CGSize(width: 125, height: 125)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        print("handleTap called!")
    }
}
```

I'm using it in a ViewController, like this: 
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController {
    private var boxView: BoxView = BoxView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.boxView)

        /* block: XXX
        self.boxView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(self.view)
        }
        */

    }
}
```

The gestures don't seem to work as soon as I uncomment the block marked "XXX" in the ViewController which adds the SnapKit constraints. Can someone help me understand what's going on here? Am I using the gesture recognizer correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I missed an important constraint, adding a "size" constraint on the custom view (BoxView) fixed it.

```
func construct() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.frame.size = CGSize(width: 125, height: 125)

    self.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.size.equalTo(self.frame.size)
    }

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```